# Error in running a simple Spark program

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have a very simple SparkPi.java program that I put in a jar file (sparktest.jar). When I submit it to the Spark cluster in local  mode, everything is fine (command is: `spark-submit --cl ass JavaSparkPi --master local  --num-executors 4 ./sparktest.jar 50`). However when I change it to run on YARN cluster (I have a single-node local Hadoop cluster in my own machine), it gives me the following error (command is: `spark-submit --cl ass JavaSparkPi --master yarn-client  --num-executors 4 ./sparktest.jar 50`):

```
 For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://win-7h2roeh9rhb
:8088/proxy/application_1423255988135_0062/Then, click on links to logs of each
attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1423255988135_0062_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1425685976713
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://win-7h2roeh9rhb:8088/cluster/app/application_14232
55988135_0062
         user: hadoop
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application finishe
 with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.run(ClientBase.scala:5
2)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcce
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variable has been properly set. What can be the problem?